# PHP Direct SMTP Send + Attachment

Tags: php, smtp, email-attachments

I'm using xpertmailer to send email direct to the remote SMTP server following an MX lookup.  This works really well and works on an old closed source NAS drive running PHP4 and on current PHP5 boxes.

```
<?php

define('DISPLAY_XPM4_ERRORS', true); // display XPM4 errors
require_once '/path-to/SMTP.php'; // path to 'SMTP.php' file from XPM4 package

$f = 'me@mydomain.net'; // from mail address
$t = 'client@destination.net'; // to mail address

// standard mail message RFC2822
$m = 'From: '.$f."\r\n".
     'To: '.$t."\r\n".
     'Subject: test'."\r\n".
     'Content-Type: text/plain'."\r\n\r\n".
     'Text message.';

$h = explode('@', $t); // get client hostname
$c = SMTP::MXconnect($h[1]); // connect to SMTP server (direct) from MX hosts list
$s = SMTP::Send($c, array($t), $m, $f); // send mail
// print result
if ($s) echo 'Sent !';
else print_r($_RESULT);
SMTP::Disconnect($c); // disconnect

?>
```

I'm now trying to add an attachment to it, but I've no idea how to get an attachment to be included and sent.

Anyone any ideas how I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out http://xpertmailer.sourceforge.net/documentation/? "Attach" is the 5th item in the list on the left, and looks fairly simple to get running with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
$m = new MAIL;

// attach source
$a = $m->Attach('text message', 'text/plain');

$f = '/path/image.gif';
// attach file '$f', disposition 'inline' and give a name 'photo.gif' with ID value (this ID value can be used in embed HTML images)
$a = $m->Attach(file_get_contents($f), FUNC::mime_type($f), 'photo.gif', null, null, 'inline', MIME::unique());

echo $a ? 'attached' : 'error';
```

Comment: Thanks.. that helps a lot :)